# Why might SetMathAlphabet{\mathit} not change the alphabet?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, alphabet

I'm trying to change the math alphabet. The following MWE compiles with neither error nor warning in my latex installation, but the math font is not actually changed. The math alphabet remains the same as the default text. Oddly, the `\DeclareMathAlphabet` command works fine, so: the first phrase is different from the last two. If it matters, I'm using pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{normal}{OT1}{ppl}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\palit}{OT1}{ppl}{m}{it}

\begin{document}
$\palit{somemathinpalatino}\ somemathinpalatino$ \textit{somemathinpalatino}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\mathit` is not the normal math italic, but is “text italic in math” and should be called explicitly. If you want Palatino style math italic letters, either load `mathpazo` or `newpxmath` (and `newpxtext` for the text fonts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math alphabet `\mathit` is for “text italic in math”, which is very different from the “math italic” used for single letters without markup.

In order to use some font with family name, say, `fabc`, you have to define a symbol font. For instance

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{abcletters}{OT1}{fabc}{m}{it}
```

and then define letters to use the `abcletters` symbol font:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{b}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{c}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`c}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{y}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`B}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{abcletters}{`Z}
```

Spacing will be wrong, particularly when exponents or subscripts are involved, because a math letter font needs specially crafted parameters for the characters.

Comment: @JohnPerry Please, remove the obsolete comments

Comment: Alas, I don't seem to have reputation enough to vote you up (I thought I did) but I did select yours as the correct answer. Thanks again.